# Trying to make the earth - don't see the Mapping sub-menu

Tags: texturing, uv

In the "Realistic Earth" Blender Guru video by @andrewprice there is a handy submenu in Texture called "Mapping". It has "Sphere Projection" which allows an image to map to a UV sphere "automatically" without UV unwrapping. I'd like to try but don't see it in my Texture menu. 2.74, tried both Cycles and Blender render setting.

1. what can I do to get that "magic button"?
2. is there a better way (without UV unwrapping)? - although it's a classic, the video is almost
   4 years old.

I'll treat UV unwrapping separately.

IMAGES:

Left: from [YouTube (How to Create a Realistic Earth in Blender, Blender Guru)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=489&v=6GLIbPKpgQ4),

Right: my screenshot

[image: YouTube screen shot Blender Guru Earth][image: My screenshot]

Comment: May it be that the left one is Blender Internal and the right one is cycles? In Cycles, the texture in the texture tab isn't necessarily related to the material you are editing. Set up nodes to get mapping in Cycles.

Comment: Maybe try that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeWTTINkUG0
Havent watched, don't know if it's good or easy to follow. Other than that google for "cycles material nodes"

Comment: Bingo! That is *exactly* what I needed! Sometimes I am frightened by how useful nodes are. Thanks @bortran!! I found it easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice of @bortran I started watching [Blender 2.7 Tutorial #12 : Image Textures & Bump Maps #b3d](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeWTTINkUG0) and within minutes I made the earth.

`Generated` coordinates and just select `Sphere` in the Image Texture.

[image: earth nodes]
[image: earth rendered 2]

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer so people know there is an answer. If you have another or a better answer, please leave it and if it helps I can accept it instead. Thanks!